# Website not updating content on first refresh

Tags: php, pdo

On my website I'm listing data from the database with the use of `$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`. Everything is working fine except that after changing the database and redirecting with `header()` the user must refresh the page again to actually see the changes. I don't know what is causing this and it seems odd that the content is there but only upon a second refresh. Any help would be great. Thanks.

This is the code that is listing data back to the user.

```
public function getCoilInfo ($coil_id) {
    //Database Connection
    $db = Database::getInstance();

    //Query to select all information from `coils` tables based off $coil_id
    $query = $db->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `coils` WHERE coil_id = :coil_id");
    $query->execute(array(
        ':coil_id' => $coil_id
    ));

    //Return array with results
    return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

I then reference the following class like this:

```
$coil = new Coil();
$coilInfo = $coil->getCoilInfo($_GET['coil_id']);

echo $coilInfo['coil_name'];
```

Comment: Provide the code you are using.

Comment: @chris85 See updated question.

Comment: Sounds like browser cache. I don't see your `header` code, but you can try cache breaking by appending timestamp query string to the redirect url

Comment: @JeffPuckettII That was my first thought but turning off caching doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Are you using a framework or just straight PHP files?

Comment: It may be server side cache, I edited my comment: try the cache breaker query url

Comment: @TylerSebastian I'm using Bootstrap and jQuery but my PHP is completely untouched by frameworks.

Comment: please provide some structure information - i.e. where the second piece of code is

Comment: @TylerSebastian What piece of code do you mean?

Comment: "I then reference the following class like this..." that piece of code

Comment: @TylerSebastian That is just how I use the array by `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`